# How do I send to RTMP using DJISDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

I bought a Phantom 4 pro for development testing,

I have received and tested DJISDK sample source and the DJI Go 4 app has a LiveStreaming menu, but it is not in the sample code.

The DJISDK tutorial has information about iOS but not Android.

How do I send to RTMP using DJISDK?

Comment: sorry , i can not English 
It's a Google translator.,,